# Googlebot crawl anomaly due to blocked resources by Zopim

Tags: googlebot, crawl-errors

I am using Zopim live chat to enable chat support in my website, but Googlebot is showing error due to some unreachable resources from zopim service. I have attached a screen capture of the error.

[image]

Due to blocked resources, Googlebot is putting the page into crawl anomaly group and not indexing the page. What can I do about this?

Comment: I'm very sure, the cause of noindexing is different one

Comment: Are you sure the above URLs are causing Crawl Anamoly? My website blocks the exact resources and I do not have any such error. Find out what exactly is causing this issue? Is it serving a static 404 page without serving the 404 request?